# While in a Class to Show Posts

Tags: php, class, loops

i have a class lets call it page and it retrieve somw rows from database (array) and returns them.
i want somthing like this:
when a class called in a div (`<div> $posts->show()</div>`) like wordpress and other CMSs i want the div to be looped.i mean like

```
<div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div>
```

within the class.

Comment: *(reference)* [PHP control structures](http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php)

Comment: you'll need to re-word your question if you want intelligible answers..

Comment: Your question, as it stands, is really just a collection of words. You really should make it clearer what it is you are trying to do. Perhaps put in some php code you have tried and maybe a html output you are expecting.

Answer (score 1):

**If I understood you: try this**

```
 $i = 0;
    $table = null;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($your_query))
    {
        $table .= "<div>".$i++."  {$row[0]}</div>";
    }

    echo $table;
```

Comment: there's a missing parenthesis on the while

Answer (score 0):

This should put

```
1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4
```

between your div tags:

```
$i = 1;
$a = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  array_push($a, $i);
}
echo implode('</div><div>', $a);
```

Comment: ok this works but i want to get mysql result from a class
like:
while(have_posts()){
echo $theclass->ID;
}
which the have_posts() function detects if the Class ID (a var) is less than the mysql_num_rows or not
my actuall problem is to set the ID in the class and return it in a while outside the class